# Compare two lists of dictionaries in Python. Return non match

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have two lists of dictionaries like below:

```
incidents = [
    {
        "incidentId": "RWS03_949563",
        "incidentState": "REGISTERED"
    },
    {
        "incidentId": "RWS03_949565",
        "incidentState": "REGISTERED"
    }
]

incidents_db = [
    {
        "incidentId": "RWS03_949563",
        "incidentState": "PENDING"
    },
    {
        "incidentId": "RWS03_949565",
        "incidentState": "PENDING"
    }
]
```

I want to compare the `incidentId` with each other and return the non_match. This is my code now, but it returns just the two items, because it is comparing the whole item instead of only the `incidentId`. What's a good way to do this?

```
non_match = []
for i in incidents:
    if i not in incidents_db:
        non_match.append(i)
```

Comment: whats the purpose of ur code if `incidentId` in both list of dictionaries have the same values?

Comment: It's just a unique ID. I'm having some 'incidents' in my database and I get new incidents every 5 minutes. I need to compare those two lists with each other. When incidentID isn't present in the database list, I need to add the item @ombk

Comment: so you actually want the code to check if a new instance in `incidents` is not yet in `incidents_db` and add it there?

Comment: Yeah. But it happens sometimes that the `incidentState` is different in the example above. But I only care about the `incidentId`. If a instance is from `incidents` is already in `incidents_db` with the same ID, I don't need to add the item @ombk

Comment: check the code i sent, it solves ur issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
incidents = [
    {
        "incidentId": "RWS03_949563",
        "incidentState": "REGISTERED"
    },
    {
        "incidentId": "RWS03_947565",
        "incidentState": "REGISTERED"
    },
        {
        "incidentId": "RWS02_947565",
        "incidentState": "REGISTERED"
    },
        {
        "incidentId": "RWS05_947565",
        "incidentState": "REGISTERED"
    }
]

incidents_db = [
    {
        "incidentId": "RWS03_949563",
        "incidentState": "PENDING"
    },
    {
        "incidentId": "RWS03_949565",
        "incidentState": "PENDING"
    }
]
```

```
for i in incidents:
    c = 0
    for j in incidents_db:
        if j["incidentId"] == i["incidentId"]:
            c+=1
    if c==0:
        incidents_db.append(i)
```

```
#output
incidents_db

[{'incidentId': 'RWS03_949563', 'incidentState': 'PENDING'},
 {'incidentId': 'RWS03_949565', 'incidentState': 'PENDING'},
 {'incidentId': 'RWS03_947565', 'incidentState': 'REGISTERED'},
 {'incidentId': 'RWS02_947565', 'incidentState': 'REGISTERED'},
 {'incidentId': 'RWS05_947565', 'incidentState': 'REGISTERED'}]
```

```
for i in incidents:
    c = 0
    for j in incidents_db:
        if j["incidentId"] == i["incidentId"]:
            c+=1
    if c==0:
        i["incidentState"] = "PENDING"
        incidents_db.append(i)
```

```
#output

[{'incidentId': 'RWS03_949563', 'incidentState': 'PENDING'},
 {'incidentId': 'RWS03_949565', 'incidentState': 'PENDING'},
 {'incidentId': 'RWS03_947565', 'incidentState': 'PENDING'},
 {'incidentId': 'RWS02_947565', 'incidentState': 'PENDING'},
 {'incidentId': 'RWS05_947565', 'incidentState': 'PENDING'}]
```

Comment: the last three examples of the output are modified examples i changed the `RWS##` or the code in them `47` instead of `49`

Comment: @LucasScheepers welcome, and next time ask your question clearly :p

Comment: Could you maybe explain what happens with `c+=1` and `if c==0`. I don't understand it

Comment: @LucasScheepers if they are matching, c receives +1, you can add `c+=1`  a `break` , but i dont know ur level in python so i kept it as simple as possible. if c gets incremented by 1 it means that the value in incident shouldnt be added to the database.
if `c==0` it means u havent incremented anything. therefore its a good instance

Comment: Aaaah yeah of course. And c is resetting to zero every item in the `incidents` loop. I see. thanks again

Comment: @LucasScheepers btw i mis explained, you can add `break` after the `c+=1` and not swap it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to compare two specific items from the dictionary. Do this:

```
non_match = []

for incident_dict in incidents:
    for db_dict in incidents_db:
        for key, value in incident_dict.items():
            if not db_dict.get(key, False):
                non_match.append(value)
```

Comment: I won't be able to do this, because `incidents` is a list

Comment: @LucasScheepers Yeah I just saw it but I can edit the code to work with lists, I'm doing it now

Comment: The lists are never the same length. But still need to compare them

Comment: @LucasScheepers I just have one question, do you want to compare the incidents' first dictionary's element with all the elements of incident_db dictionaries or only the respective index.

Comment: @LucasScheepers I edited the code again to work with variable lengths of lists. Can you check and see if this is what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah I want to compare the `incidents'` fist dictionary's element with all the first elements of `incident_db` dictionaries. I will check your new code

Comment: @LucasScheepers check the code i provided

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare only " incidentId"

```
non_match = []
for i in range(0,min(len(incidents),len(incidents_db))):
    if incidents[i].get("incidentId") != incidents_db[i].get("incidentId"):
        non_match.append(incidents[i])
print(non_match)
```

Comment: Hmm never mind. When the lists of dictionaries varies from length, I get a index out of range error of cours :(

Comment: @LucasScheepers this code  compares the elements from both dictionaries in a parallel way. thats why you are getting this error

Comment: Yeah I know, do you know another solution? @ombk

Comment: i edited . compare with small list incidentId

Answer (score 0):

```
non_match = []
for a,b in zip(incidents, incidents_db):
    if a.get("incidentId") != b.get("incidentId"):
        non_match.append(a.get("incidentId"))
print(non_match)
```

Comment: So if the list of dictionaries from `incidents` is longer than the `incidents_db` list, it just skips the rest of the items. I don't want that :(